# emacs can invoke shell and execute commands-- can they act on Emacs buffers?

Tags: shell, emacs, buffer

I use Alt-! (Alt-Bang) a lot in Emacs. One of the big things I use it for is

```
Alt-! cat $logfile | grep 'this' # show me one kind of event
```

or sometimes

```
Alt-! cat $logfile | grep 'this' | wc -l # count that one event's occurrences
```

Two things:

1) No tab-completion from this prompt: why not?

2) What if instead of **$logfile**, I want to scan one of the Emacs buffers?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? I have tab completion from the `shell-command` prompt. (tab is bound to `minibuffer-complete-shell-command`)

Answer (score 3):

To scan an Emacs buffer, use `M-|` instead of `M-!`: it passes the region as input to the command. Use `M-1 M-|` if you want the output of the command to replace the region.

For the particular command you mention, use `M-x grep` if you want to see all matches. Or you can open it and see the matches with `M-x occur`.

Answer (score 1):

`Alt-|` does is shell-command-on-region

with a(ny) numeric prefix (e.g. C-u 1 Alt-|) the region is replaced by the result, otherwise that appears in new buffer

Comment: n.b. `C-u` provides a default value (4^n when you press `C-u` n times), so when the number is irrelevant, or just needs to be some positive integer, you needn't use `C-u 1` when you can just use `C-u` on its own (or `M-1` or `C-1`).